# vector<shared_ptr> ptrs, ptrs.pop_back() returns void

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Есть следующий класс:

```
class InteractiveMode {
public:
    /.../
private:
   static vector<std::shared_ptr<InteractiveMode>> stackStates;
    /.../
};
```

И два метода:

```
 void InteractiveMode::Life() {

    while(1) {
        /.../
        auto state = std::make_shared<InteractiveMode>(*this);
        stackStates.emplace_back(state);
    }

}

void InteractiveMode::back() {
    if (stackStates.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Stack of states is empty!";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    shared_ptr<InteractiveMode> ptr = stackStates.pop_back();
    /.../
}
```

При компиляции получаю следующую ошибку:

> error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'std::shared_ptr' requested
>            shared_ptr ptr = stackStates.pop_back();

То есть `stackStates.pop_back()` возвращает `void` вместо нужного мне `shared_ptr<...>`. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно пытаетесь получить значение из `void`-функции.

`pop_back` только удаляет, ничего не возвращая. Если нужно последнее значение - используйте `back()`.